# Escapar de caracteres especiales PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, php7

Hay alguna forma de **escapar de los caracteres especiales** de una manera **mas "elegante"** para hacer  **consultas SQL con PHP?**
no me cuadra usar algo como

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE nombre='".$conexion->real_escape_string($_POST['nombre'])."' ";
$conexion->query($query);
```

¿hay algun otro método que **que no sea este, y que sea más corto?**

Comment: disculpa si te sueno tedioso, pero podrías darme un ejempo? o una documentación de lo que me estás diciendo? te lo agradecería mucho

Comment: mysqli, PDO aun no conosco

Comment: muchas gracias!!! era lo que necesitaba

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes ajustar `$conexion->query()` para que acepte parametros. La consulta contendra valores `?` que seran representados por los parametros usando `mysqli_prepare()` (https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.prepare.php):

```
SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE nombre='?'
```

Luego a cada parametro `?` se se asigna un valor usando bind_param( tipo, valor). Donde `tipo` puede ser `i` integer, `d` decimal,`s` string o `b` blob (ver https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php). Cada llamada a `bind_param()` establece los valores en el mismo orden en que los `?` aparecen .

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, "SELECT * from table where field1=? and field2=?");
$stmt->bind_param("i",123);
$stmt->bind_param("s","test");
```

Al llamar a `$stmt->get_result()` La consulta quedara como:

```
SELECT * from table where field1=123 and field2='test'
```

con todos los ajustes necesarios en cuanto a escape de caracteres especiales.

Considera el siguiente ejemplo.

```
function query($sql, $params=[]){

  if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql)) {

    foreach($params as $param){
      $type="s";
      // puedes ajustar $type segun el tipo del valor de $param
      $stmt->bind_param($type, $param);
    }
    $result = $stmt->get_result();

    return $result
  }
}
```

Y la llamada seria:

```
$conexion->query("SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE nombre=?",[ $_POST['nombre'] ]);
```